# laravel build in auth specify view to use

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to specify what view to use for the built in auth in laravel? It currently uses views/auth/login.blade.php but i want for example to use views/admin/auth for the admin section then use another view for the front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using the AuthenticatesUsers trait your controller will have getLogin, postLogin and getLogout methods which I think is what you are referencing on your routes, something like this:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

If you give a look to AuthenticatesUsers the only thing it does is to check if view auth.authenticate exists if not it returns auth.login

You could override this method or create a new one with the view you want to return and change your route

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
  public function newLogin()
  {
    return view('admin.auth');
  }
}
```

And change your Route to

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@newLogin');
```

Another thing you could need in the future is to change the default login path and redirected after logout path, that can be done by defining in your controller two properties as protected:

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/where/to/redirect/after/login';
protected $loginPath = '/another/login/path';
```

Comment: thanks, i just figured it out. the methods i needed to override were in the routes lol, didnt think to look there. but what you wrote is useful. gonna bookmark. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste the function you want to modify to your `Auth\AuthController` and overwrite.